# Lambda timeout after trying to connect to firestore

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-firestore

I have a continuously running lambda(30 min interval) that is getting timedout when trying to connect to firestore. I don't really know why it is happening like this.. I have used at the beginning of the lambda

```
 context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

Can anyone help me to solve this...please....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does you lambda function has access to the internet? This is a really common error, you will need to setup your VPC's subnet to allow it to reach the internet.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: not only subnet, but also proper security group egress rules

Comment: @VladyslavUsenko oh yeah, that as well, but that is implicit. Subnets are trickier and not that straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

There's a 15 minutes constraint for Lambda functions. If you go over that limit, they'll timeout and there's no way to work around it.

You can see it in the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/):

> You can now set the timeout value for a function to any value up to 15
>   minutes. When the specified timeout is reached, AWS Lambda terminates
>   execution of your Lambda function. As a best practice, you should set
>   the timeout value based on your expected execution time to prevent
>   your function from running longer than intended.

You can also check [AWS Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html). While some of these limits can be raised by contacting AWS, the maximum execution time is not one of them.

If your function runs in less than 15 minutes, you can simply increase the timeout for your function via the console (under basic settings, I am attaching a screenshot) or via aws-cli (or via frameworks such as AWS SAM, Serverless, etc. if you're using one).

Check how to change the limits [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html)

[image]

However, I would try to understand why your function is timing out when connecting to Google's Firestore. I don't know anything about Google Cloud, but maybe you should allow outbound traffic on it. Maybe the timeout should be increased, but maybe Firebase is blocking any outbound traffic, making your Lambda to timeout. If your Lambda is outside a VPC, it should be able to connect to the internet seamlessly, so the connection with Firebase should be fairly quick.

One other thing I suggest is to run your [Lambda function under Node 8](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/) as you can take advantage from [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) and get rid of `context` and `callback` objects which are very confusing at first.